# failed to pull image from public docker hub

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd

I set up the .gitlab-ci.yml file for CICD. it pulls image from the public docker. I got the error below. I am sure why it is fails.

ERROR: Job failed: failed to pull image "xxxxxx/validate_dag" with specified policies [always]: Error response from daemon: manifest for xxxxxx/validate_dag:latest not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown (manager.go:205:0s)

```
test-dag-dev:
    image: "xxxxxx/validate_dag"
    stage: test
    script:
      - python -m unittest -v -b
```

Comment: Not much to go on without the full image name. If it's public on Docker Hub it should be ok to share it, but don't if you think otherwise. All I can say without more information is to check the tags available in Docker Hub and make sure your using the correct tag for that image. You should be able to see all the tags from the overview page on Docker Hub, then the `Tags` tab. Here's an [example from the Gitlab image itself](https://hub.docker.com/r/gitlab/gitlab-ce/tags?page=1&ordering=last_updated). Once you have a tag, update your image in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` to `xxxx/validate_dag:1`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was missing the tag, e.g.:

```
test-dag-dev:
    image: "xxxxxx/validate_dag:<tag>"
    stage: test
    script:
      - python -m unittest -v -b
```